# argo workflow retryStrategy override

Tags: argo-workflows

is there any way to override values of "WorkflowTemplate-retryStrategy" in argo ?

Currently we are using hardcoded retryStrategy in Argo WorkflowTemplate like below (sample code):

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: WorkflowTemplate
metadata:
  name: workflowtemplate-1
spec:
  entrypoint: task-template-1
  arguments:
    parameters:
    - name: "test"
      value: "testing"
  templates:
  - name: task-template-1
    retryStrategy:
      limit: 1
      retryPolicy: "Always"
    inputs:
        parameters:
          - name: "test"
```

Is there any way where we can override it as part of workflow arguments (or anything similar)?
like commented "#" values in below code:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  name: sample-workflow
spec:
  workflowTemplateRef:
    name: workflowtemplate-1
  # retryStrategy:
  #   limit: 3
  #   retryPolicy: "Always"
  arguments:
    parameters:
  #  - name: "retry"
  #    value: "2"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep! Just set up a workflow parameter for the retry limit.

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: WorkflowTemplate
metadata:
  name: workflowtemplate-1
spec:
  entrypoint: task-template-1
  arguments:
    parameters:
      - name: "retry"
        value: "1"
  templates:
    - name: task-template-1
      retryStrategy:
        limit: "{{workflow.parameters.retry}}"
        retryPolicy: "Always"
      container:
        image: docker/whalesay:latest
        command: ["false"]

---

apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  name: sample-workflow
spec:
  workflowTemplateRef:
    name: workflowtemplate-1
  arguments:
    parameters:
    - name: "retry"
      value: "2"
```

If you submit sample-workflow, you'll see that it retries twice instead of just the default once.

**Note:** templating the `limit` field was [introduced in 2.11.0-rc1](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/releases/tag/v2.11.0-rc1).

If you're stuck with an earlier version, there is a [workaround](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/issues/3646#issuecomment-667360407).

Comment: Michael Crenshaw, I tried this before and after your post also, but it is not working. throwing me this error: Failed: invalid spec: unrecognized type: int32 

====== 
I am using below argo version: 

argoproj/workflow-controller:v2.9.3
argoproj/argocli:v2.9.3

====== 
is the example working for you? 
do you see any issue with argo version compatibility ?

Comment: @AkashAgrawal I tried with 2.12.11. I'll try again with 2.9.3. It's possible `retry` was an integer field back then. Over time they've had to convert integer fields to strings so that they can be templated.

Comment: @AkashAgrawal updated with a comment about version compatibility.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Michael Crenshaw!! I will try to run the sample with latest argo version.